# How can I pass reference to call_user_func?

Tags: php, reference, callback

Consider the following example :

```
function myTest(&$var)
{ 
    $var++;
    echo "var = {$var}\n";
}

$x = 42;
call_user_func('myTest', $x);
```

It shows the warning :

> Warning: Parameter 1 to myTest() expected to be a reference, value
>   given in /home/alain/workspace/echo/echo.php(57) : eval()'d code on
>   line 7

Note: code written on an online sandbox, explaning the eval.

Any idea how I can pass reference to `call_user_func` family functions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found my answer on the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) :

> **Note:**
>
> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by
> reference.

They also give a trick to do the job :

```
$x = 42;
call_user_func_array('myTest', array(&$x));
```

Comment: **NO!  this is deprecated (pass by referenced is deprecated after php 5.3)  !**

Comment: Hey @T.Todua, this code seems to work on PHP 7. Do you have any link showing this? Cheers. Alain

Comment: @T.Todua this actually specifically avoids call-time pass-by-reference by using an array literal or straight variable (no `&`) rather than something incorrect like `call_user_func('myTest', &$x);`. The function signature still has to have a reference parameter, and this ensures that the variable the function operates on is still the same variable, rather than a copy made by `call_user_func`.